# Equality using Parseval's theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

Is it the following allowed using Parseval's theorem?

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty} g(k) f(x)^2 dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\infty}^{\infty} g(k) F(k)^2 dk$$

with $F(k)$ the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.

Comment: Did you mean $g(x)$ in the left-hand integral?

Comment: No, I really mean g(k), that is the confusing part indeed and the reason why I am not sure about the solution...

Comment: Call the integral $F(k)$, then $F(k)=F(0)$ so $F$ is constant, which is false for general $g$.

Comment: Hmm I see, so the two sides are not equal to each other?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Parseval's. It's the way it is formulated. You're probably missing something in the problem.

Comment: The integral on the left depends on $k$, and the integral on the right does not.